# Error with URLConnection

Tags: android, google-places-api, urlconnection

I was just trying to get a feel of the JacksonJson library. For that, I was trying to get JSON data from the Places API into a String.

My key is valid (I tested in browser, and in another app), but I'm getting errors. Here's the code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Cloud&types=food&language=en&sensor=true&location=33.721314,73.053498&radius=10000&key=<Key>");
            URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("The Line: ", "" + line);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This is the output from logcat:

```
02-14 12:29:07.407: D/libc-netbsd(16792): getaddrinfo: maps.googleapis.com  return error = 0x8 >>
02-14 12:29:07.813: D/libc-netbsd(16792): getaddrinfo: maps.googleapis.com get result from proxy >>
02-14 12:29:08.706: D/libc-netbsd(16792): getaddrinfo: maps.googleapis.com  return error = 0x8 >>
```

I have the Internet permission in my manifest. I have no idea why this isn't working, or what these errors are.

Comment: This error denotes that the android device could not convert maps.googleapis.com into its corresponding IP address. Looks like your device has a internet proxy and is pointing to a bad DNS server. Try changing your DNS server IP to 8.8.8.8 in your android device network settings. Also if its a emulator and not a real device, it could be a different issue.

Comment: @KiranKumar But on the same phone, another app using the same API/Key is working fine...

Comment: @KiranKumar Its a real device, and I already use Google's DNS :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right way to hit the URL. You are passing its parameter to the url just to to write bytes to output stream and then request the url

```
   URL googlePlaces = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Cloud&types=food&language=en&sensor=true&location=33.721314,73.053498&radius=10000&key=<Key>");
```

This is the right way to hit the URL.

```
  url=new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json");
```

and then put all the parameters to the params Map;

```
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("query","Cloud");
            params.put("types", "foods");....like this put all
```

and then build the body..

```
    StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
            // constructs the POST body using the parameters
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
                bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                        .append(param.getValue());
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    bodyBuilder.append('&');
                }
            }
            String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
```

Here Body contains all the parameters which you can't directly request by the URL but you have written it to the OutputStream and then make a request and write the bytes

```
               byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
               OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
               out.write(bytes);
               out.close();
```